# ListBoxEditItem Visibility not working as expected

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml and I am trying to set the ListBoxEditItem for Content="3" without using the ElementName for ck because I want to set the Visibility directly and not have the CheckBox.  Why does the Visibility work for Content="2" ListBoxEditItem and not Content="3"?  How do I set the Visibility directly?

```
<StackPanel>
        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit EditValue="{Binding test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
            <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
            <Visibility>Hidden</Visibility>
        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>

        <dxe:ListBoxEdit StyleSettings="{dxe:RadioListBoxEditStyleSettings}">
            <dxe:ListBoxEditItem Content="1" />
            <dxe:ListBoxEditItem Content="2" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ElementName=ck}" />
            <dxe:ListBoxEditItem Content="3" Visibility="{Binding test, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </dxe:ListBoxEdit>
        <CheckBox x:Name="ck" Visibility="{Binding test, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <TextBlock Text="some stuff" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=ck}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed DataContext in the binding like so:

```
<dxe:ListBoxEditItem Content="3" Visibility="{Binding DataContext.test, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```